# MonoTouch: Default.png not being added to .app bundle

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Using MonoTouch 4.0.4.1 and MonoDevelop 2.6b3

Our Default.png file is marked as "Content"

When we build the app, the resulting .app file when viewed using "Show Contents" in finder does not contain the Default.png.

The png is 320x480 32 bit

In previous versions the Default.png was being added correctly.

Has something changed?

Comment: MonoDevelop 2.6 RC1 was released today. You might want to check it and, if not fixed, quickly fill a bug report (before the final build is made)

Comment: The RC solved the debugging issue, but still no splash screen in the .app or when the app launches.

Comment: I get the same error with MD 2.6, and it's been like this for a while.

Comment: I tried, without problem, with both 2.6 beta2 and 2.7 (master, built from GIT), but I cannot update to RC1 right away to confirm it.

Comment: I have reopened Bug #200 as this is not fixed in R1 . See: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=200) in the MonoDevelop beta releases that will not copy the content in root over to output. You can either use a post-build command to copy (and then resign!!!) the content or you can use the stable version of MonoDevelop (2.4.x)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you also set the "Copy to output directory" to "Copy if newer".

Comment: This will just result in additional files being copied to the output directory, not the app bundle.

Comment: This is actually a correct answer. Your file won't get into the app bundle without "Copy to output directory". The only reason it doesn't work for you is because of the bug in MonoDevelop. What's with the down vote?

Comment: This is a common piece of misinformation, but please believe me, I designed and implemented the app bundle creation support in MonoDevelop. I downvoted it to stop it spreading further, sorry.

Comment: So are you saying that all you have to do is to set the file as Content and it should get added to the app bundle? No need to copy to output dir?

Answer (score -1):

Ok guys, I guess i found a workaround, please give this a try

Im running MD 2.6RC1, in order to your content files are being included in the
final bundle, delete them from your project, then save your project close MD,
then reopen MD and add again your content files to your project, don't forget
to mark them as content ;)

this worked for me.

UPDATE:

***This bug has been resolved, Just update to MonoDevelop 2.6 RC2***

Alex

Comment: This won't make any difference.